# Google Play error "Version XXXX is not served to any device configuration"

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, multiple-apk

I'm having the following error:

> Version 102001019 is not served to any device configuration: all
>   devices all devices that might receive version 102001019 would receive
>   version 103001019.

The problem appeared after I decided to separate APKs for devices with different screen sizes. I have also already multiple APK configuration, with 4 APKs regarding to the texture compression.

So I've set important setting to those APKs in the following way and it doesn't work:
 - versionCode:**103001019**    screenSize: **xlarge,large,normal**
 - versionCode:**102001019**    screenSize: **large,normal**

The numbers 2 and 3 should be the differentiating increasing part of the version code to let Google choose the right version for me.

The docs say:

> If you have one APK that's for API level 4 (and above) and small -
>   large screens, and another APK for API level 8 (and above) and large -
>   xlarge screens, then the version codes must increase in correlation
>   with the API levels. In this case, the API level filter is used to
>   distinguish each APK, but so is the screen size. Because the screen
>   sizes overlap (both APKs support large screens), the version codes
>   must still be in order. This ensures that a large screen device that
>   receives a system update to API level 8 will receive an update for the
>   second APK.

But as far as I don't need to filter on the API version, and I have overlapping in screen sizes, my variant should be Ok. Right?

Any advice would be very much appreciated!

P.S. I have very slow internet connection and 300+MB single APK+OBB size, so it is a pain to check all possible combinations manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What the Play Store does is always pick the highest version number for each device. So given different screen sizes:

- xlarge `103001019` is only available, so pick `103001019`
- large `103001019 > 102001029` so pick `103001019`
- normal `103001019 > 102001029` so pick `103001019`

As you can see, your `102001019` is not selected for any devices as it only supports a strict subset of devices compared `103001019`.

Make sure your multiple APKs are designed to support a unique portion of the devices you wish to support.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
Unfortunately when I set the screen sizes without overlapping on different version, I receive an error message saying: version **102001019** can not be served to some devices that a **103001017** (previous version) was fine. And then a list of features of the APK without any specific direction on the matter of the problem.

I checked all the other filters and can't find any problems. Is there any way to diagnose the matter of a problem (some utility)?

Comment: Like it says, users already have `103001019` on their xlarge, large, and normal devices. If you're replacing any one of those densities, then your new version number needs to be larger than the old one.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The docs are appeared to be a bit unclear for me, as I thought I've already increased the version number, by changing from 017 to 019.

Comment: Thank you. I've finally figured that out. The version codes that worked for me are:
xlarge 103101019 (this 31 appeared to be very important)
normal, large 103001019

Answer (score 1):

I also received that problem when I uploaded the APK at the first time but I noticed that API level 18-17 when viewing APK details.  Therefore, I added this code to AndroidManifest.xml to specify the maximum API level

```
 <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="18"
        android:targetSdkVersion="23"
        android:maxSdkVersion="23" />
```

After doing this, the problem is solved :)